# AJAX Session Cookie in OS X Dashboard Widget

Tags: jquery, ajax, macos, widget, dashboard

I am developing a Dashboard widget for OS X. Using AJAX I am interacting with a remote API. I am using jQuery to ease the ajax implementation. The API I am working with requires a login and uses normal session cookies. I am successfully logging in but doing a subsequent AJAX call fails due to not being logged in. It appears that the widget/jQuery/ajax is not storing/using the session cookie. What am I missing?

```
function login(e,p) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "sessions.json",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            login: e,
            password: p
        },
        success: function(res) {
            getProjects();
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
}

function getProjects() {
    $.ajax({
        url: url + "projects.json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
        },
        success: function(res) {

            console.log(res);
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the solution to this problem while researching something else.

[Phonegap App communicate with Rails 3 App using authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905976/phonegap-app-communicate-with-rails-3-app-using-authentication)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing your answer:

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

For me, however, what worked in Dashcode was setting Widget Attributes > Network/Disk Access > **Allow External File Access** to *checked*.  I was looking for some way to store browser cookies, and by systematically toggling this and "withCredentials," in the end, it seems that withCreds did nothing for me whereas Allow External File Access was the key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Strange that for me, neither of these options work. Maybe something is missing for my dashboard widget config as I originally hand built it rather than Dashcode. Funny thing is in Dashcode, the widget works/runs fine, but save as "*.wdgt" file and deploy to dashboard it it fails to work from session not persisting but it does in Dashcode. My project is here: https://github.com/daluu/autosmsclients/tree/master/macosx