# Phonegap App communicate with Rails 3 App using authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, devise

I am trying to write an iOS app using Phonegap to communicate with my Rails3 app. I cannot figure out how to handle authentication. I am using Devise/Warden in my Rails app.

I am able to login successfully in my iOS app via ajax but then subsequent calls are giving me a "Unauthorized". It appears that the session cookie isn't getting set in my iOS app.

How do I keep my iOS app aware of my rails authenticated session?

Comment: what'd you come up with? i'm interested in the answer to this question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was two fold.

First I had to add this to my ajax requests in the iOS app:

```
xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
}
```

as in...

```
$.ajax({
    url: ....,
    type: "GET",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    complete: hideLoader,
    error: function(xhr,txt,err) {
        // you can't get back anyways
        window.location.hash = "";
    },
    success: function(data,status,res) {
        window.location.hash = "";
    }
});
```

Second I had to add this to my Application Controller in the Rails app:

```
def protect_against_forgery?
  unless request.format.json?
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: where is the first line of code added? i understand it's a block that would be sent via ajax, just not sure where it'd go... are you using phonegap?

Comment: The first line is added to the ajax request. I am using phonegap and jquery. I edited my post.

Comment: thanks, i upvoted you. so it looks like you are overriding the protect_against_forgery to allow the request to come in... seems like it sorta defeats the purpose of that method though doesn't it? so does this allow the cookies to be set? what authentication are you using? devise?

Comment: Yes, it does override forgery protection for json requests. Authentication works the same way as normal it just makes request replay attacks a little easier. I wasn't worried about that in this case but if you are worried about it then your javascript has to use a hidden form and pull it's forgery protection token and include that in the request.